# Using subquery with update SQL

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update, subquery, ibm-midrange

I have Table 1 : EMP as below

```
       ID   NAME             CITY             AMT        
       -------------------------------------------
        1   sajani           Bangalore        0          
        2   Prashanth        Bangalore        0          
        3   Jayvin           Bangalore        0
```

Table 2: EMP1

```
 ID   NAME1            CITY1            AMT1    
 ---------------------------------------------
  1   Sajani           Bangalore        10      
  1   Sajani           Bangalore        10      
  2   Prashanth        Bangalore        10      
  3   Jayvin           Bangalore        10
```

ID is the Key and is common in both the files. I want an Update SQL to update the amount field of Table 1 using Amount field of table 2, which gives the result as below.

Result:

```
       ID   NAME             CITY             AMT        
       --------------------------------------------
        1   sajani           Bangalore        20          
        2   Prashanth        Bangalore        10          
        3   Jayvin           Bangalore        10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
update emp
    set amt = (select sum(e1.amt) from emp1 e1 where e1.id = emp.id);
```

You can check if the values match using:

```
update emp
    set amt = (select sum(e1.amt) from emp1 e1 where e1.id = emp.id);
    where amt <> (select sum(e1.amt) from emp1 e1 where e1.id = emp.id);
```

Comment: And what if I want to update the records only if its not matching

Comment: If what is not matching?  Perhaps you should ask a new question.